# Parabola equation in Fortune algorithm for building Voronoi diagram

Tags: geometry, algorithms, conic-sections

in DeBerg's *"Algorithms and Applications"*, the part about Voronoi diagram, i have encountered the following formula for parabola arising in the beach line for a site point:

$$\beta := y = \frac{1}{2(p_{j,y}-l_y)}(x^2-2p_{j,x}+p_{j,x}^2 + p_{j,y}^2-l_y^2),$$
where $(p_{j,x}, p_{j,y})$ is the site point and $l_y$ is sweep line $y$ coordinate.

Why $\frac{1}{2(p_{j,y}-l_y)}$ multiplies $(x - p_{j,x})^2?$

I think equation of the parabola must be

$$y = (x - p_{j,x})^2 + (p_{j,y}+l_y)/2.$$

[image]

EDIT: Thanks to Erick Wong, who pointed out that equation from the book is scale-invariant. But i don't understand, why they would need scale-invariance? And why this divisor?

Comment: Could you define your terms, such as site point and sweep line $y$ coordinate?

Comment: What makes you think that is the equation of the parabola?  It seems like you are using the fact that it passes through the point $(p_{j,x}, p_{j,y}+\ell_y)$.  But this is true for any equation of the form $y = a(x-p_{j,x})^2 + (p_{j,y}+\ell_y)$, so this doesn't determine $a$.  The equation in the book is much more plausible because it's **scale-invariant**: when you double $x,y,\ell_y,p_{j,x},p_{j,y}$, the relation still holds.  This is not true for what you are suggesting.

Comment: @RoryDaulton From the diagram, this is probably just a basic question about the equation of a parabola given the focus (site point) and horizontal directrix (sweep line).

Comment: @ErickWong scale-invariant, huh! i think you can form it as an answer:) Only i don't understand why they need the equation to be scale-invariant.. And why with exactly this divisor?

Answer (score 1):

Just noting that the given equation of the parabola should be:

$y=\frac{1}{2(p_{j,y}-l_y)}\left(x^2+2p_{j,x}x+p^{2}_{j,x}+p^{2}_{j,y}-l^2_y\right)$

Comment: Please don't use the answer field to draw attention to a minor edit.

Answer (score 0):

Too see why we need this multiplier $\frac{1}{2(p_{j,y}-l_y)}$ for $(x - p_{j,x})^2$ we must notice what shape of parabola changes with sweep line movement.

At the very beginning, when new site is just hit the line it is effectively just a vertical line and while sweep line moves downward it became wider and wider.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow stumbled across this equation trying to find it myself. The equation actually can be found by using the vertex form equation of a quadratic graph;

*y* = *a*(*x* - *h*)<sup>2</sup> +*k*

It should be understood that the vertex of the parabola is equal to the midpoint of the line representing the shortest distance between the generator and the sweep line. Hence, the vertex

(*h*, *k*) = (*p*<sub>*j*, *x*</sub>, <sup>(*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> + *l*<sub>y</sub>)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>)

Thus, giving you
*y* = *a*(*x* - *p*<sub>*j*, *x*</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + <sup>(*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> + *l*<sub>y</sub>)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>

This seems to be where you got to. *a*, however, needs to be accounted for as it defines the concavity and scale of the graph. To determine *a*, another point on the graph is required. For this, take the point on the parabola horizontally on the right of the generator referring to the figure below.

[Point *n* on parabola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVMsW.png)

The distance between *p*<sub>*j*</sub> and *n* is equal to the distance between *p*<sub>*j*</sub> and the sweep line. Thus, the coordinate of

*n* = (*p*<sub>*j*, *x*</sub> + *p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> - *l*<sub>*y*</sub>, *p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub>)

By substituting this point into the quadratic formula, *a* can be found

*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> = *a*(*p*<sub>*j*, *x*</sub> + *p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> - *l*<sub>*y*</sub> - *p*<sub>*j*, *x*</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + <sup>(*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> + *l*<sub>y</sub>)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>

*a*(*p*<sub>*j*, *x*</sub> + *p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> - *l*<sub>*y*</sub> - *p*<sub>*j*, *x*</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = *p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> - <sup>(*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> + *l*<sub>y</sub>)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>

*a*(*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> - *l*<sub>*y*</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = <sup>(*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> - *l*<sub>y</sub>)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>

*a* = <sup>(*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> - *l*<sub>y</sub>)</sup>⁄<sub>(2(*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> - *l*<sub>*y*</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)</sub>

*a* = <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>(2(*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> - *l*<sub>*y*</sub>))</sub>

Therefore, the overall equation would be
*y* = <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>(2(*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> - *l*<sub>*y*</sub>))</sub>(*x* - *p*<sub>*j*, *x*</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + <sup>(*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> + *l*<sub>y</sub>)</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>, and would be why <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>(2(*p*<sub>*j*, *y*</sub> - *l*<sub>*y*</sub>))</sub> multiplies (*x* - *p*<sub>*j*, *x*</sub>)<sup>2</sup>.

This may not be the cleanest method but this is the method I used to derive the same formula you posted. Hope this helps.